# reload selected cell of a tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swift4

So I have a tableView which is first rendering data fetched from one json and then will get second json which consist of last updated parameter.

No using this I want to update only those cells in tableview whose update value is greater than 1 day.

reload data is doing the job but updating all the cell.

Is there any way to update only specific cells of tableview based on json result?

Answer (score 0):

func for reload cells by indexPath:
[reloadRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reload `UITableView` at specific Indexpath by using below method

```
func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you NSFetchedResultsController, read about it here: 
https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3